# Epic game - ubuntu 20.04

Tags: launcher, games, screen

I am newbie, I recently move to ubuntu 20.04 from windows.
When i try to launch Epic game store this is problem:
[Epic launcher problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C62Az.png)

I have no ideal what to call this problem. Distorted screen? Scratch screen? sync problem screen?
Is there any one meet this situation and have solution?
Thank for reading.